# Get rid of characters between two characters in Splunk

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I'm currently facing a little problem.

I'm a beginner with Splunk, and I need to print a temperature in a single value widget.

I want the temperature to have °C at the end.

When I'm doing this: `| eval value = value +"°C"`

The printed value is `80.00 °C`.

I want `80°C` to be printed.

I also tried to use the Major value and trend which is supposed to allow me to add a unit after a value but it prints it very tiny compared to the temperature value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `eval` function [`round()`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval) first (presuming "`value`" is just a number):

```
| eval value=round(value)+"°C"
```

Alternatively ... use `replace()`:

```
| eval value=replace(value,"\.[^°]+","")
```